# PHP Beginner: Trying to add premade contact form

Tags: php, contact-form

I'm trying to add a premade e-mail contact form to my homemade html page. I found the code here: http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php. I added the Html to a div in my page, and that seems to have worked just fine. I think the problem is with the php part. Do I need to add that code to the same html file? Or should I create a new .php file in the same folder with the copied code? I tried creating a .php file, but when I click submit, it just takes me to the page and shows me the php code. Thanks!

Comment: if you see php, then the file is not *.php or your not running it on a server or ...

Comment: Yes, you need to create a second file. Just read the second paragraph and respond with what you don't understand, because the instructions are very clear on what you have to do and what you need to change.

Answer (score -1):

You can just create a single php file and put the html and php codes there.

Just remember that in the HTML part specifically in the form tag, the action should be the file name of your php file because the function is in the same page..

Comment: Downvote? Yall see that I can't add comment yet to the question, right?